# I want to get current time, but I received GMT. What is wrong?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to get current time, but I received GMT.  I added locale but it didn't helped me. I uses an iPod touch. What is wrong?

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSLocale *locale =[NSLocale currentLocale];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[NSDate date] description]];
```

UPDATE: I use NSDateFormatter because I need show

```
2012-03-17 12:20:33
```

instead

```
2012-03-17 12:20:33 +0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I founded nice solution.

```
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit
                                            fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString * stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", components.year, components.month, components.day, components.hour, components.minute, components.second];
```

**Another solution**

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[formatter setTimeZone:zone];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"Date %@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can also

```
NSTimeZone* local = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; 
NSInteger secondsOffset = [localTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then you can just add it into your existing date.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "ZZZ" is a dateformat that specifies GMT. See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

By the way, don't confuse (NS)Locales with (NS)Timezones. They aren't the same. Locales define styles, like "01.02.2012" vs "02/01/2012", timezones define ... timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously why you are going through a dateformatter at all here? `NSDate *date = [NSDate date];` will give you a date that has the current time.

Comment: [NSDate date] gives me only gmt time, but I need a local time.

Comment: yes, but you cant extract that info reliably without a formatter.  I dont see any getTimeOfDay functions in its interface.